# Libreoffice Calc : Fill in a range of cells with a known start and end value. Automatically

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

I have two cells separated by some empty cells. Values in parentheses.

A1  [ 23 ]

A23 [ 433 ]

I want the spreadsheet to figure out the best way to increment the values between them, based on how many cells need to be filled, and fill them in.

I don't care about accuracy or rounding, or precision. Easiest solution please?

Note: Excel has a built-in feature for this, but I need a solution for Calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **A2** enter:

```
=(A$23-A$1)/(23-1)+A1
```

and copy downward.

*(should work for Excel, libreoffice, Google Sheets, etc.)*

Comment: Works as advertised. Thanks!